# How can I return a 2 dimensions value to main method?

Tags: java

```
// TO GET AVERAGE OF ENTIRE ARRAY
private static int average(int[][] array){ 
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
            int rowPcol= row*col;
            int average= sum(array) / (rowPcol);

        }   
    }
    return average;
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method average(int[][], int) in the type Hw8P1 is not applicable for the arguments (int[][])
```

How can I return this to my method?

Comment: You are attempting to invoke sum() on a 2D array, not a 1D array.

Comment: You are not passing the correct parameters to your method.

Comment: @Vizkos How do we know `sum()` needs a 1D array? The method he posted is `average()`. The exception says nothing about `sum()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting an exception is that you have a compilation error in your code.  Always correct compilation errors BEFORE you attempt to run your code.

It in not clear what is causing your compilation error.  The error message says that you are attempting to call a method with signature `average(int[][], int)` ... but the `average` method you showed us does not have that signature.

I suspect that you have shown us code that doesn't match what you are actually attempting to compile and run.  The most likely explanation is that you have forgotten to recompile it.  Either way, we can't help you fix your code if you show us the wrong version of the code.

The compilation error points to this being a problem with the way you are making the call, not a problem with the way that the result is being returned.

One final point is that the average of a collection of integers is rarely an integer.  You probably should be calculating the average as a floating point value; e.g. a `double`.

Comment: How can I get how many values are in a arrary and use that value for something else?

Comment: Use the .length property on the array.

Comment: Indeed, I'm surprised that you need to ask that, since your code already uses `array.length`.  Did you write it yourself?